# Java RMI - total bytes transferred

Tags: java, rmi, distributed

I am making Java application using classic TCP sockets and Java RMI and I would need to find out the total size of all transmitted data, for statistical purposes. For TCP sockets, I can simply count the bytes written into them - but is there any way I can measure how many bytes in total RMI sends and receives? I know I could use some external tool like Wireshark, but is there any way that would allow me to do it within the application itself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can accomplish that creating your own socketfactory

Comment: @rpax Indeed. Just create a socket factory that provides sockets whose stream methods return counting streams. A trivial exercise in multiple delegation.

Comment: @EJP I've never heard of socket factories before, but it looks like it will do exactly what I need. Thanks!